# Connections on Hermitian subbundles

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am following Kobayashi's book *Differential geometry of complex vector bundles*, which is proving a challenge to follow in detail, as many of the proofs leave up to the reader to fill in the gaps.

### **Preliminaries**

My question is related to Section I.6 **Subbundles and quotient bundles**: here we have a rank $r$ holomorphic vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ endowed with a Hermitian structure $h$ and a rank $p$ holomorphic subbundle $S \subset E$. We can define the quotient bundle $Q = E/S$ fitting in the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow S \rightarrow E \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0$$
and $Q$ being $C^\infty$ isomorphic to the orthogonal complemente $S^\perp$. Consider the canonical Hermitian connection D (metric compatible and $D^{0,1} = \bar{\partial}$). We can decompose, taking sections with values in the subbundle

$$D \xi = D_S \xi + A \xi~~~~~~~~\forall \xi\in\Omega^0(S)$$
$$D \eta = D_{S^\perp} \eta + B \xi~~~~~~~~\forall \eta\in\Omega^0(S^\perp)$$

and it is easy to see that $D_S$ is the Hermitian connection in $S$, $A$ is a $Hom(S,S^\perp)$-valued (1,0)-form, $B$ is a $Hom(S^\perp,S)$-valued (0,1)-form, and furthermore, for $\xi \in\Omega^0(S),\eta\in\Omega^0(S^\perp)$ we have
$$ h(A\xi,\eta) = - h(\xi,B\eta)$$

### **My problem**

I want to deduce the analogues of Gauss-Codazzi equations for Hermitian vector bundles, i.e. that the curvature act like
$$
R = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
R_S - B\wedge B^* & D^{(1,0)}B\\
-D^{(0,1)}B^* & R_{S^\perp} - B^*\wedge B
\end{array}\right)
$$

Using frames for the $C^\infty$ decomposition $E = S\oplus S^\perp$ greatly helps. If we use the notational convention $1\leq a,b,c \leq p$, $p+1\leq \lambda,\mu,\nu \leq r$ it is very simple to split the indices (summing over repeated indices everywhere) and see that

$$DDe_a = (d\omega^b_a + \omega^b_c \wedge \omega^c_a + \omega ^b_\lambda \wedge \omega^\lambda_a)e_b
+ (d\omega^\lambda_a + \omega^\lambda_c \wedge \omega^c_a + \omega ^\lambda_\mu \wedge\omega^\mu_a)e_\lambda
 $$
$$
DDe_\lambda = (d\omega^a_\lambda + \omega^a_c \wedge \omega^c_\lambda + \omega ^a_\mu \wedge \omega^\mu_\lambda)e_a
+ (d\omega^\mu_\lambda + \omega^\mu_c \wedge \omega^c_\lambda + \omega ^\mu_\nu \wedge \omega^\nu_\lambda)e_\mu
 $$
Here one can easily identify the $S$ and $S^\perp$ curvatures:
$$ R_Se_a = (d\omega^b_a + \omega^b_c \wedge \omega^c_a)e_b$$
$$ R_{S^\perp} e_\lambda = (d\omega^\mu_\lambda + \omega^\mu_c \wedge)e_\mu$$
and here the book states
\begin{align*}
R e_a = (R_S + B\wedge A + DA)e_a\\
R e_\lambda = (R_{S^\perp} + A\wedge B + DB)e_\lambda
\end{align*}
but I am certainly confused about how to calculate the action of either $A\wedge B$, $DA$ or $DB$ since I don't know which version of the Leibnitz rule to implement, namely:
$$ (A\wedge B) e_a = A^\lambda_b \wedge B^c _\mu e_a$$
or inverting the order of the wedges.

**Clarification**: for the $A,B$ operators one can see that their matrix expression in the chosen split frame is
$$Ae_a = \omega^\lambda_b e_\lambda~~ B e_\lambda = \omega^a_\lambda e_a$$